# understanding sum of random variables which may take infinity with positive probability.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

$X_1, \dots, X_n$ are i.i.d random variables, $\text{Prob}(X_i= -\infty)>0$ is allowed. could anyone tell me what does it mean by and why this is true: $\{X_1+\dots+X_n=-\infty\}\subseteq\{X_1+\dots+X_n\le nc\}$ for some $c\in \mathbb R$, constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean $\text{Prob}(X_i=-\infty)>0$ is allowed.

You could imagine a 6-sided die, except instead of the normal lables the die says $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, and $-\infty$, with each label having probability $\frac{1}{6}$.

Now suppose I sample $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ by rolling these dice, and I happen to know that $X_1+X_2+X_3 =-\infty$. Note that this means at least one of the dice had to show $-\infty$. But more importantly, $-\infty$ is less than any finite number, so in particular $X_1+X_2+X_3 \leq a$ where $a$ is any real number.

I suspect you will be interested in what happens as the number of terms in the sum ($n$) goes to infinity. But still, if $X_1+\cdots+X_n=-\infty$, then $X_1+\cdots+X_n \leq a$ for any real number $a$. In particular, we can choose any constant $c$ we like and say $X_1+\cdots+X_n \leq nc$.

Note that you have to be a little careful with arithmetic when dealing with $\infty$. We know $-\infty \leq a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and $-\infty+a=-\infty$ for any $\mathbb{a} \in \mathbb{R}$. However, something like $(-\infty)-(-\infty)$ is indeterminant. So we could not consider the random variable $X_1-X_2$, since its value is indeterminant when both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $-\infty$.

Comment: Oh yes, the notation $\{X_1+\cdots+X_n=-\infty\}$ is a shorthand. It means "the event in which $X_1+\cdots+X_n=-\infty$ is true."